# Can I implement google analytics for web-view/browser within IOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, statistics, google-analytics-api

I have an application that forwards people to a web view, browser after they have found a product. Now, i want to implement a method to track traffic and pixel analytics once a user is on the web view browser.

There will be e-commerce, so ideally it will be great if there is a way to track analytics from with the browser navigation all the way up to successful checkout. 
Your help/insight will be really helpful. I appreciate your help in advance.

Thank you

Comment: There is no way actually since, I was asking to track even if the web view ends up opening safari/chrome.

Answer (score 1):

yup you can track the traffic. Set up campaign tracking from where its forwarded. GA will then capture this information and attribute to the corresponding channel.
You need to setup e-commerce tracking in the web property as well.

Comment: No, is not possible without a JS snippet on the 3rd party website.